# Check state from imported component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Much of a basic question. Can I pass the state property to another component? So if I create a login app and after a successful login from API call I set the state of `loggedInUser: 12345` in say a component called Login.js

```
export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data:[],
            loggedInUser: 12345
        }
    }

    render(){

        return(
            //Return the this.state.loggedInUser
        )

    }
}
```

How can I pass `this.state.loggedInUser` from `Login.js` to another component where I've imported `Login.js`?

For example, in my `Page1.js` I have `import Login from './Login'`

Can something like this be achieved? I just want to pass the `this.state.loggedInUser` value to any page where it us imported.

Thanks.

Comment: To allow components to communicate with each other, something such as **redux** is typically used.

Comment: I find Redux very very confusing. Is there any way to do it without using Redux/Flux and using pure react-native? I only want to share 1 single state between components.

Comment: The "React pattern" is to pass whatever you need to child components via `props`. Are you talking about passing information to a parent component?

Comment: I want to set the state in 1 component and use that state in any component where I import that component. So I can know if the user is logged in or not and if logged in what is the user id.

Comment: Redux is actually super simple, very elegant and pretty indispensable (downsides - a lot of boilerplate reducers everywhere!) It may be a bit heavyweight for your purposes which is fine, but if you do want to check out look at the author's (Dan Abramov) free course on egghead.io https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: In you use case, the logged in data is going to used by every other component you use. It makes sense to have this functionality in your top-level components, then you can just pass it down via `props`. Every child component of your top-level ()e.g. PageContainer.js or whatever) will have access.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Checking the tutorial. thanks a ton for the link. One last question. Does including Redux makes my application slow?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, redux is probably best practice here. But here is an example of accomplishing this with vanilla react.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      logginUser: undefined
    }

    this.handleUserState = this.handleUserState.bind(this);
  }

  handleUserState = (userInfo) => {
    this.setState({logginUser: userInfo})
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Login handleUserState={this.handleUserState} />

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
  }

  loginUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

     <--- make call to api for userInfo here and pass it to the call below --->

    this.props.handleUserState(userInfo)
  }

  render =() => {

    return(
        <div>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.loginUser} />
        </div>  
    )
  }
}
```

Basically what's happening here since you are importing Login into another component, you will have that 'Parent' component act as the state manager and save the user data at that level. You then pass the function that updates the state to the Login component and call it once you have the user data to update it with.

I hope this helps!